# Where to find the Embedded Media Rendering after installing Brightcove Connector for 10.1.1

Tags: brightcove

I have installed the brightcove connector for sitecore 10.1.1 and was able to add video using RTE's embed Media feature.

But I am not able to find the Embed Media rendering in the package for the connector which was present in the earlier releases. Instead there is a `Experience Rendering` added to the package which is just a view rendering.

**In sitecore 10.1.1**
[image]

**Sitecore 10.1.1 : screenshot of Layout/Renderings.**
[image]

**In 9.3**
[image]

Is the Embed Media rendering removed and have to be custom developed to achieve the same or there is some issues with the package?

Any reference to documentation on setting up other than the official docs will be of great help.

Docs followed : https://integrations.support.brightcove.com/sitecore/user-guide.html

Comment: Your screenshots shows that you're checking in `Layout/Layouts/Renderings` path instead of `Layout/Renderings` (one extra `Layouts`).

Comment: It's not present in the layout/Renderings path. The rendering was present at this location in the package so I added that. Lemme add the screenshot of Layout/Renderings item node as well